# How to remove empty spaces in SQL

Tags: sql

Can anyone help me to remove empty spaces from the beginning of a string. In a column, there are different number of empty spaces in each entry. How to eliminate them? Thanks a ton in advance

Comment: `trim(leading ' ' from the_column)` or `ltrim(the_column, ' ')`

Comment: `TRIM(column)` to remove leading and trailing space's. `TRIM(LEADING column)` to remove only the leading ones.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted to remove the empty spaces from the beginning of a string,Use `LTRIM`.

```
SELECT LTRIM(YourColumn)
FROM YourTable
```

if you wanted to remove all the spaces,use the below script (specific to `SQL server`).

```
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(YourColumn,' ','')))
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: LTRIM and RTRIM are product specific functions, and the question has no dbms specified.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LTRIM` or `TRIM` depending on your database/version.

Comment: But wont replace also remove space's between words?